# "macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg is incompatible with this version of macOS" while installing Haskell on OS X mojave

Tags: xcode, haskell-stack, macos-mojave

While running the following code block,

```
$ cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
$ open macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

The installer warned

> This package is incompatible with this version of macOS and may fail to install.

And when I choose 'Install Anyway', it fails.

How can I possibly get it work?

Some possibly relevant environmental versions:
    OS: macOS 10.14.5
    xcodebuild -version: Xcode 11.2.1
    gcc --version: gcc (Homebrew GCC 9.2.0_1) 9.2.0

Bigger Context: 
I was setting up haskellstack, following instructions on https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/

while running `$ stack setup` I came accross

> configure: error: in '~/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.6.5.temp/ghc-8.6.5':
>   configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
>   See 'config.log' for more details
>   Received ExitFailure 77 when running

and per the Notes section of the instructions, I ran

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

and it says

> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

And then (following the same instructions) I ran

```
$ cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
$ open macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Answer (score 30):

My MacOS is 10.14.6

I found a solution in another website by MacrossEO, see https://donatstudios.com/MojaveMissingHeaderFiles

I had to removed the command line tools with 'sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
open macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Comment: Go figure, I also had to rm this folder and reinstall as you indicate - the pkg I had in this location would fail to install...

Comment: I don't see a `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/` after reinstalling `Xcode` and the `packages` should be 'SDKs

Comment: I am running OSX12.4 and apparently, things have changed, [see here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-10-release-notes#3035624)