# How to solve "fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found" error when installing R package from CRAN archive?

Tags: r, cran

I am trying to install the R package "splusTimeDate" from the CRAN archive:

`install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/splusTimeDate/splusTimeDate_2.5.4.tar.gz", type="source", repos=NULL)`

However, I get the following error:

```
Installing package into ‘/Users/username/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/splusTimeDate/splusTimeDate_2.5.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 151455 bytes (147 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 147 KB
* installing *source* package ‘splusTimeDate’ ...
** package ‘splusTimeDate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: ‘clang version 14.0.6’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX13.3.sdk’
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/R/arm64/include    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c align.c -o align.o
In file included from align.c:19:
In file included from ./align.h:11:
In file included from ./timeUtils.h:16:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R.h:43:11: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
# include <stdlib.h> /* Not used by R itself, but widely assumed in packages */
          ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [align.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘splusTimeDate’
* removing ‘/Users/username/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/splusTimeDate’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/4z/tvbvjjk101qdx6y31dds68040000gq/T//Rtmp3fp00q/downloaded_packages/splusTimeDate_2.5.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Please help...my Phd depends on me being able to install this package and its reverse dependencies and imports...!

I am working on an Apple M1 MacBook Pro with R (64-bit Silicon) Version 4.3.1 and have installed xcode.

Answer (score 0):

This may be resolved by providing clang the required headers, by linking them to `/usr/local/include`. Please disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) and do:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/include
sudo ln -s $(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include/* /usr/local/include
```

You may need to check and backup what is present in /usr/local/include.

I have successfully installed my R package (`rmarkdown`) after this.

This is a complicated Apple issue and it has consumed me so much time to solve it. Here are some of the related links:

- [stdlib.h not found when installing R package on mac · Issue #137 · catboost/catboost](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/137)
- [xcode - "macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg is incompatible with this version of macOS" while installing Haskell on OS X mojave - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897928/macos-sdk-headers-for-macos-10-14-pkg-is-incompatible-with-this-version-of-maco)
- [Xcode 10 Release Notes | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-10-release-notes#Command-Line-Tools)
- [xcode - Can't compile a C program on a Mac after upgrading to Catalina 10.15 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278260/cant-compile-a-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrading-to-catalina-10-15)
- [macOS软件编译时找不到头文件解决方法[更新10.15] – 知了](https://zhile.io/2018/09/26/macos-10-14-install-sdk-headers.html)